# how to position lists inside multirows and fix cline error with vertical lines

Tags: lists, positioning, multirow, cline

I am quite a newbie so please forgive my ignorance.
Well they say 1 picture = 1000 words, so this is kind of what i want to achieve:
[image]

Now my attempt through latex lead to this:
[image]

So I guess my problems are:
1) how can I fix the vertical lines? (This must be related to \cline command...)
2) how can I position the lists in a better way? By that I mean, that all lists will fill in the whole length of their columns (maybe I could adjust the spacing between the items too). My guess is that the "&" symbol except for separating columns also aligns text making things a bit complicated
Thanks in advance!!!

```
%
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\rmfamily\mdseries\Large}
\subsectionfont{\rmfamily\mdseries\itshape\large}
\setlength\parindent{0em}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
% table
\section*{Table}
\vspace{-0.7cm}
\hrulefill
\vspace{0.2cm}
%
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.6cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.6cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.6cm}|}
\hline
Title1:  & Title2: &Title3:  \\
\hline
 \multirow{6}{*}{} \\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
    \begin{description}[itemsep=0pt]
        \item One
        \item Two
        \item Three
        \item Four
        \item Five
        \item Six
    \end{description}
\end{minipage}%
                 &   
                 \multirow{12}{*}{
                 \begin{minipage}[c]{\hsize}
            \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0pt]
                \item Text1
                \item Text2
                \item Text3
                \item Text4
                \item Text5
                \item Text6
                \item Text7
                \item Text8
                \item Text9
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{minipage}%  
        }          
                    &   
    \multirow{12}{*}{             
                 \begin{minipage}[c]{\hsize}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item other1
            \item Other2
            \item Other3
            \item Other4        
            \item Other5
            \item Other6
            \item Other7
        \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%         
}              
\\
 \cline{1-1}
 Other:\\
  \cline{1-1}
\multirow{4}{*}{} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
    \begin{description}[itemsep=0pt]
        \item[1] Foo1
        \item[2]  Foo2
        \item[3] Bar1
        \item[4] Bar2
        \item[5] FooBar
    \end{description}
\end{minipage}%
            &                &                 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the different vertical white space between consecutive items intentional? Please also add a minimal example document that shows how you achieved your current output.

Comment: Oups sorry for not posting a snippet of my code..i will edit my initial post with it.Thank you. About the white space, it's not intentional, not really..I was just experimenting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a place to start from.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum,1]{nosep,leftmargin=*,before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip},after=\vspace{-1\baselineskip},label*=\arabic*.,leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{}L|L|L|}
\hline
\thead{Title 1:} & \thead{Title 2:} & \thead{Title 3:}\\
\hline
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{\linewidth-\tabcolsep}}
\begin{tabenum}
  \item item
  \item item
  \item item
  \item item
  \item item
  \item item
\end{tabenum}\\
\hline
Others:\\
\hline
\begin{tabenum}
  \item item
  \item item
  \item item
  \item item
  \item item
  \item item
  \item item
  \item item
  \item item
\end{tabenum}\\
\end{tabular}&
    \begin{tabenum}
      \item item
      \item item
      \item item
      \item item
      \item item
      \item item
      \item item
      \item item
      \item item
      \item item
      \item item
      \item item
    \end{tabenum} & 
        \begin{tabenum}
          \item item
          \item item
          \item item
          \item item
          \item item
          \item item
          \item item
        \end{tabenum} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My answer is basically the same as leandriis, but I just wanted to point out that you can use arraystretch to change the spacing in a tabular environment.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers..@leandriis your reply seems to be completely different from how i was trying to acieve it but yours is much better i believe..i am gonna experiment a little bit with it and return.
I have noticed though that i may have some issues with aligning in the center and maybe filling more space but as i said i should give it a better try and may twist some things..thanks again

Comment: hey, i think @leandriis has actually given the solution so..case closed:)
may i also ask how can i increase the space between the different items?